# Assignment does not occur when using assign() with %>%?

Tags: r, dplyr

Nothing seems to happen when I attempt to use the assign() command with the %>% operator. I can of course simply work around this without the operator, but want to understand why this happens for the future.

I can show what I am talking about via the following code:

```
g <- "var"

assign(paste0(g, "_name"), 1)

paste0(g, "_name") %>% assign(2)
```

After running this block, var_name is equal to 1, not 2. The more normal syntax works as expected, but the dplyr version does not. I have a more complex example that generates warning messages that show that calculations within the second assignment command are being computed, but the output is not assigned as expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @akrun It would help if you came right out and said what you meant instead of trying sarcasm, which is notoriously hard to read on internet comments. But, trying to read between the lines: if you want to tag other questions as dupes, please go ahead. I am not obliged to systematically weed out questions; I interact haphazardly and do what I can.